# A wide vertical ListView inside a horizontal scrollview in Android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, xamarin

I have a vertical listview in my Android app.

It is styled to look like a table with columns i.e. each listview item template has multiple textviews inside a horizontal linearlayout. Each textview has a width e.g. 12 textviews, each one 200dp means the width of the listview needs to be 2400dp.

This listview needs to scroll vertically which is fine as that's the built in functionality of a listview. However, due to the large width that the listview can be I need it to also scroll horizontally too (as I don't want to use weights on the textviews and squish to fit on the screen width).

I thought of putting the listview inside a horizontal scrollview. Then setting a width of 2400dp on the listview and the horizontal scollview width to match_parent.

However, the scrollview doesn't seem to be extending wide enough to show the full width of the listview. It scrolls horizontally but not enough. Where am I going wrong with this approach?

**In the page:**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent">
      <ListView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="2400dp"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**ListView Item**

```
<LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Long text here..."
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The TextViews inside add up to exactly 2400dp and you give your listview exactly 2400dp width but i think the listview itself will need a few dp for example for the small scrollbar to scroll  the items vertical i would assume that this are the pixels you are missing